# How can I program a batch script to re-write a specified string?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm making a batch script that will automatically compile some projects for me and I want to know how (if possible) to program said script to first locate a specified file (i.e. .txt, .ini, .cpp, .py,  ect), then find a specific line of text and finally re-write said line to something that I specify. An example would be as follows:

```
find file >

locate line #x >

re-write as %TEXT%

save(?) >
```

I added a question to `save` because I don't know if such a function needs to be made or if the script can simply re-write the line upon execution.

Another thing I would like to experiment with is instead of seeking a specific line, would bt to seek a specific string to be re-written. This example would go (theoretically) as such:

```
find file >

locate string "Sample text" >

re-write as "New sample text" >
```

The goal of this would mainly be to compensate for scripts where a certain string will not always be on the same line or that will vary in location.

Currently I can write a simple text document with this script:

```
(
  echo %SampleText%
) > %DOCUMENT%.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've done a lot with batch scripts but never anything like this.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have updated my question with some of my code I'm working with.